# Jquery Variable Function for hover in seperate element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery file I am using to resize a background image so it doesn't get stretched or squished. It looks like this;

```
(function ($) {
    var wheight = 0;
    var $imagebackground = 'images/bg2.jpg';
    var wwidth = 0;
    var ratio = 0;
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = $imagebackground;

    $(img).one('load', function (e) {

        ratio = img.width / img.height;
        $('#background-wrap').html(img);
        lets_scale();

    });

    if (img.complete) img.trigger('load');

    function lets_scale() {
        wheight = $(window).height();
        wwidth = $(window).width();

        $('#background-wrap').width(wwidth).height(wheight);

        if (wwidth / ratio >= wheight) // If the browser is wider than the image
        {
            $('#background-wrap img').css({
                'width': wwidth,
                'height': Math.ceil(wwidth / ratio),
                'margin-top': Math.ceil((wheight - wwidth / ratio) / 2)
            });
        } else {
            $('#background-wrap img').css({
                'height': wheight,
                'width': Math.ceil(wheight * ratio),
                'margin-left': Math.ceil((wwidth - wheight * ratio) / 2)
            });
        }
    }

    $(window).bind('resize', lets_scale);
    $(window).bind('orientationchange', lets_scale);

})(jQuery);
```

Then the HTML is like this;

```
<div id="background-wrap"></div>
```

The css for that div is;

```
#background-wrap
{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

I want to take the variable `$imagebackground` and load a set image when a user hovers in the `mainnav` div list have the background image change. I have the li class set different for each link and want to pass that to the variable for the background image change. The html for the div and list is;

```
<div class="mainnav">
    <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav1"><a href="hsna">Link1</a></li>
        <li class="nav2"><a href="life">Link2</a></li>
        <li class="nav3"><a href="happening">Link3</a></li>
        <li class="nav4"><a href="porchrokr">Link4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It seems that the `$imagebackground` variable could be a function that changes it's value based on the user hovering in the list in `mainnav`, but i seem to be getting stuck shoving a function into that variable

Comment: Where is your js for the hovering part? also is your background image a background image or an image inside of a div that displays in the background? your js suggests that it is an img in a div and not a background image

Comment: There is no JS for the hovering part yet.  I am trying to figure out how to drop it into a variable so the hover image will be affected by the resizing script i have.  The img is part of a div that functions as a background.

Comment: Your current image is "images/bg2.jpg", I assume you want to change that image to something else when you hover the mainnav. All you need to do is change the source of the image. The resize function has nothing to do with the source of the image. You don't need to worry about that

Comment: I understand that part.  I want to change the var $imagebackground into a function so that I can have a different image load when a user hovers over the different links in the mainnav list

Comment: No, all you need is a hover function that changes $('#background-wrap img') source, $imagebackground is only used once. You don't need to worry about that. How do you want the image to change? based on what part of the list? give examples

Comment: I want to change it based on the class of the list nav1, nav2, nav3, nav4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to have a full page background image that changes on nav hover, yet maintains aspect ratio?

Try this for your css, from [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).  Follow that link for other examples there of how to set a full page background via css.

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Then maybe set up your list like so:

```
<div class="mainnav">
    <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo">
    <ul>
        <li class="hoverbg" data-bgsrc="images/whatever1.jpg"><a href="hsna">Link1</a></li>
        <li class="hoverbg" data-bgsrc="images/whatever2.jpg"><a href="life">Link2</a></li>
        <li class="hoverbg" data-bgsrc="images/whatever3.jpg"><a href="happening">Link3</a></li>
        <li class="hoverbg" data-bgsrc="images/whatever4.jpg"><a href="porchrokr">Link4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then your jQuery looks something like this:

```
$('.hoverbg').hover(
    function(){
        $('html').css('background-image','url('+$(this).data("bgsrc")+')');
    },
    function(){
        $('html').css('background-image','url(images/bg.jpg)');
});
```

Then you can let css do the aspect ratio work.

**UPDATE** to use a different css full screen example from css-tricks, for smooth transitions

HTML:

```
<div id="bg">
  <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="mainnav">
    <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo">
    <ul>
        <li class="hoverbg" data-bgsrc="images/whatever1.jpg"><a href="hsna">Link1</a></li>
        <li class="hoverbg" data-bgsrc="images/whatever2.jpg"><a href="life">Link2</a></li>
        <li class="hoverbg" data-bgsrc="images/whatever3.jpg"><a href="happening">Link3</a></li>
        <li class="hoverbg" data-bgsrc="images/whatever4.jpg"><a href="porchrokr">Link4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.hoverbg').hover(
    function(){
        var newimg = $(this).data("bgsrc");
        $('#bg img').fadeOut('slow',function(){
            $(this).attr('src', newimg);
            $(this).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    },
    function(){
        $('#bg img').fadeOut('slow',function(){
            $(this).attr('src', 'images/bg2.jpg');
            $(this).fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: I changed everything to this using css to do the aspect ratio work, and everything is working fine.  Any suggestions on adding a smooth transition between the images?  it seems jerky, even when I used css for easing between the images it still seems to flash and load slowly.  I have tried preloading them, and that didn't seem to make a difference.  It only seems to do that in the chrome browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't fade out/in a background image with jQuery.  I think if you go to that link, and use CSS-Only Technique #2, you should be ok.  With that you'll have an element that you can fade in/out.  I'll update my answer with a rough idea in a sec.

Comment: This is what I ended up using.  I changed the fadeout fadein from slow to fast, and created a function to preload all of the images.  It works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how you can do this.

```
$('.mainnav').find('li').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        var c = $(this).attr('class');
        $('#background-wrap').find('img').attr('src', 'images/' + c + '.jpg');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('#background-wrap').find('img').attr('src', 'images/bg2.jpg');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TC9SN/

In the fiddle, even though you can't see the image change. But if you use firebug you can see the source of the image changing.

Alternatively, you can have 4 images loaded in the container to begin with. Hide them all with css except for the initial one. Then when you hover the list, you can simply add/remove class for the div to set which image to show and which to hide. This way there is no loading time for all of the images when changing them. But I guess you can also pre-load all the images first

Comment: I can see it working in jsfiddle, but I can't seem to incorporate it into my page.  Should this drop in as a separate script or should it be part of the function that changes the background-wrap size?

Comment: This should be in doc ready which I believe is your function. If you really can't get it to work, then update your question with the updated code